# How to configure gmail to send mail from android device with dynamic user name and password

Tags: android

I want to send a mail through android app using gmail smtp server without  configure credentials in code. 
suppose if i have configured Gmail ID and password in app level(Account in created in India) from that app users not able to send mails from other countries like Singapore or Africa.

Kindly suggest best solution for mail integration in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you follow [this Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android), which explains how to use the Gmail API to allow users to send emails from your own application.